# permanently decrypt messages in outlook (S/MIME)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption

I have messages encrypted with S/MIME in Microsoft Outook. These can only be decrypted with the certificate installed on the client.

Encryption stays even when saving the messagesto disk (as .msg) or moving them to another e-mail account (drag and drop in exchange).

How can I permanently decrypt these messages? 
Either for saving them on disk or inside of Exchange/IMAP.

Comment: Outlook does not have this capability out of the box.

Answer (score 3):

I just found this option in Outlook:

1. Open the encrypted email (you might need your password or whatever)
2. in the email window, use the menu item 'File/Info/Properties'
3. In the pop-up, under Security (top right), uncheck 'Encrypt email...', close, and save:

[image]

(It is grayed out in this shot, but if you have an encrypted email, it will be checked and changeable)

Comment: I don't think this will permanently decrypt the message either, as the option is grayed out after an encrypted message has been decrypted. At least on my network, after some time I'll have to enter credentials again to decrypt.

Comment: @redOctober13, did you hit 'save' at the end? You need to save the unencrypted version over the original one.

Comment: *"if you have an encrypted email, it will be checked and changeable"* -- this is not true. It is checked, and still greyed out for me on encrypted emails.

Comment: For me it is (changeable). I use this basically every day. Do you have write access the mailbox the mail is in?

Comment: It is my personal mailbox, so yes. However, it is a work account, so maybe some settings are disabled depending on organization settings.